# Metodo para capturar trexo de uma URL com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma URL, https://meusite.com/q6uzeyln32td/naoquero.html, e preciso 'cortar' para um variável o código entre as barras (q6uzeyln32td). Já tentei com o método split() com o seguinte código:

```js
var mainURL = window.location.href;
mainURL = mainURL.split('.com/');
```

Porém, sempre retorna uma Array assim:

```
Array [ "https://site", "q6uzeyln32td/naoquero.html" ]
```

O valor que quero, está com outros que não desejo.

Comment: Existem inúmeras maneiras de se fazer isso. Não diria que o `split` seja a melhor solução, mas a melhor maneira também dependeria das restrições que vc pode ter.

Comment: Uma solução ainda com o `split` seria usar somente a `/` e pegar a posição 3 do array gerado.

Comment: Vc tem pode usar `window.location.pathname`, no lugar de `window.location.href` e já vai ter a URL sem o protocolo e domínio.

Comment: Ótimo, modifiquei e funcionou normalmente, sem ser necessário fazer duas vezes a requisição... Obrigado @tvdias

Comment: Quando puder (se não me engano há um tempo mínimo), adicione uma resposta e marque a mesma como aceita.

Comment: O AP utilizou a própria pergunta para resposta. A pergunta foi revertida para primeira versão e a resposta foi colocada como wiki.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Basta utilizar a classe [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), acessar o valor do *path* e dividir na barra:

```js
// const url = window.location;
const url = new URL('https://meusite.com/q6uzeyln32td/naoquero.html')
const segments = url.pathname.split('/')

console.log(segments[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> O autor da pergunta colocou equivocada essa resposta na pergunta:

Depois de postar, li o código e pensei em fazer outro Split(), assim funcionou:

```
var mainURL = window.location.href;
mainURL = mainURL.split('.com/');
mainURL = mainURL[1];
mainURL = mainURL.split('/');
mainURL = mainURL[0];
```

Não sei se é o mais eficiente, provavelmente não, mas ai está.